# not enough input arguments - fsolve

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve this system of linear equations using fsolve,

```
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter'); 
guess=[0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 400000; 400000];
[Unkn,value]=fsolve(@handleit,guess,options);
```

Where 'handleit' is

```
function Eqn = handleit(u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9,u10,u11,u12,u13,u14,u15,f1,f2,f16)
Eqn=[...some equation is here...];
```

When I execute this I get following error,

```
Error using handleit (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
Error in fsolve (line 218)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

About the last line in error, I have substituted my guess into the handleit function and it evaluates it without any error

Comment: Could it be that `guess` should be a row- instead of a column-vector?

Comment: No, I have already tried that way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the way parameters are passed to the function. In general the function should have the format *f(x,a)* where *x* is a matrix with parameters to optimize and *a* is a matrix of fixed parameters, as in the following (somewhat unstable) example:

```
a=[2 3; 4 1];  % <-- fixed parameters
x0 = [1 2; 3  4]; % <-- trial values
test = @(x,a) exp((x(1)-a(1)).^2).*exp((x(2)-a(2)).^2).*exp((x(3)-a(3)).^2).*exp((x(4)-a(4)).^2);
fsolve(test,x0,[],a)
```

Comment: No, it isn't so. There is no parameter like `a` in my code. Besides I ran your code without `a` by taking `test = @(x) ...` and it gave the same result.